# Draw route from current location to known destination

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Using Swift in iOS, how can we display a route from the users current location to a known destination (we have the address and/or LAT LONG of the destination)?

All of the examples I've found searching SO and google are old and aren't using the current version of MapKit or Swift.

I've tried coding this from the examples I've found, but cannot seem to figure out where directionRequest call belongs.  I think I need to have the code outside of the ViewDidLoad method, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: I belive you should follow [This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/87008/overlay-views-mapkit-swift-tutorial) tutorial and then post question about specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  I have read that tutorial, as well as others from the Ray Wenderlich site, but they are overly complicated and do not address my specific question.  I tried pulling out the pieces I would need to solve the problem, but could not.